# One orthogonal basis for different quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, quadratic-forms

Let a $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $q_{a}$, the quadratic forms defined by $q_{a}(x; y ; z)=a\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)+2 x z-2 x y+2 y z .$

I want to prove that there exists a same basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ which is orthogonal to all the quadratic forms $q_{a}$.

I considered separately the quadratic forms $q_{0}(x, y, z)=2 x z-2 x y+2 y z$ and $q{\prime}(x ; y, z)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$. Then i looked for an orthogonal basis of $q_{a}$ and tried to see if i could manipulate the vectors of this basis making it orhtogonal for the quadratic form $q{\prime}$.
But it doesn't work.

Actually, i really really don't see how to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And *why* do you believe there is a single basis that will be orthogonal to all the forms?

Comment: I am asked to prove it @PaulSinclair

Comment: What is the matrix of $q_a$? What does it mean for a basis to be an "orthogonal basis of $q_a$"? Have you experimented with that definition to see under what conditions vectors might be orthogonal to each other?

Comment: The matrix of q in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is given by $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & a & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & a\end{array}\right)$. If $\left(e_{1} ; e_{2} ; e_{3}\right)$ is an orthogonal basis of $q_{a}$ we will have $\varphi_{s},\left(e_{1}, e_{2}\right)$=$a\left(x_{1} x_{2}+y_{1} y_{2}+z_{1} z_{2}\right)-x_{1} y_{2}-x_{2} y_{2}+x_{1} z_{2}+x_{2} z_{1}+y_{1} z_{2}+y_{2} z_{1} = 0$ where phi is the associated bilinear form of q. Doing the same thing with (e1;e3) and (e2;e3), we have 3 equations with 9 unknowns. @PaulSinclair

Comment: Now think about what choices for $(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ might make that expression $0$, without either point being $(0,0,0)$. For example, the first part is $0$ if for each pair $(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2), (z_1, z_2)$ at least one of the two coordinates is $0$.

Comment: Even if i find a couple (e1,e2) that makes the expression 0, i can't find a vector e3, different from (0,0,0), that makes the expression 0 when combinated with e1 and e2. As these vectors must not depend on the parameter a, their coordinates must be choosen such that the first expression gives 0. This can be interprated saying that these vectors constitute an orthogonal basis for the quadratic form $q^{\prime}$. For this, we see that the canonical basis is a good candidate. But when looking now for the other expression, there is still a problem... @PaulSinclair

Comment: If e1 is (0,0,0) for example, e1 can be written as a linear combination of e2 and e3. Therefore (e1,e2,e3) is not a basis. @PaulSinclair

Comment: Of course $(0,0,0)$ is not going to part of any basis. That is way I said "without either point being $(0,0,0)$".

Comment: Notice up above where you pointed out that you have nine unknowns, but only three equations to meet? You were mistaken - as you've also noted, you need to have $x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 + z_1z_2 = 0$, which means you also need the other half equal to $0$. So you have six equations to meet. But that still leaves you with more unknowns than equations. That means you should be able to pick values for three of the unknowns, and the solve for the other six.

Comment: Sorry, i thought you said that $e_{i}$ can be zero. You have clearly reason, i am going to try to solve the system again.

Comment: Well actually I was trying to hint that using negative values would solve your dilemma in that now deleted comment that you obviously read. But as I posted it, I realized that the particular solution I was thinking of didn't work. I had messed up my mental arithmetic. That is why I deleted the comment. So you were not wrong in thinking I was mistaken, but only in how.  Instead I went back to an earlier point before I had deluded myself.

Comment: I have a big system, difficult to solve manually. I have just remembered that i am asked to prove the EXISTENCE of the basis. If i could prove that my system have a solution it could solve the problem, but the system is nonlinear. @PaulSinclair

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132045/discussion-between-yagami-and-paul-sinclair).

Comment: I think i have it. As the matrix A of q is symmetric, A is diagonalizable and the eigenspaces are orthogonal for the bilinear form of q. So we can form the basis using the eigenvectors of A. It seems the theorem requires the form q to be definite and positive. But it works for this case i think. I am going to check it. Thanks a lot for your help @PaulSinclair